# How to set data context where Views and View models in separate library

Tags: wpf, mvvm, prism, autowired, viewmodellocator

My Projects are

1. student.shell.client
2. student.views
3. student.viewModels
4. Modules.student

student.views has student.viewModels reference, in stuent.views used `ViewModelLocator.AutoWireViewModel= true`, its not resolving the view model. Is this is not a good practise to have views and view models in different project.
How to wireup views and view models here?

Comment: Read up about viewmodel-centric design. If your code uses a locator, that's a problem you should address sooner than later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you really need separate assemblies for the views and view models? Likely not. If you want to use the view model locator, then the easiest way is for them to be in the same project/assembly.

Either that, or new up the view models in the views code behind. This will work okay if your view models don't have any dependencies. Some frown on this because the coupling between the view and view model is rather tight.

```
public partial class StudentView : UserControl
{
    public StudentView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = new StudentViewModel();
    }
}
```

Or, you can have the IoC container provide the view model in the views contructor.

```
public partial class StudentView : UserControl
{
    public StudentView(StudentViewModel viewModel)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = viewModel;
    }
}
```

This second option (IoC) is a better option given the fact that your view models will likely have dependencies that the container can provide, too.

Hope this helps.

Comment: If he's creating views in C#, that's a design flaw. Views get their data context from the template.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can have your ViewModels in a separate assembly, you just have to tell the ViewModelLocator about the new rules to use to find them.  In this blog you can see how to change the conventions to use your own convention:

http://brianlagunas.com/getting-started-prisms-new-viewmodellocator/

Very easy!

BTW @R. Richards, Prism uses DI when resolving the VMs automatically and all dependencies will be resolved with no issues and without injecting into the View ctor.  This way, the View project will not have to even reference the ViewModel project.  As long as all the assemblies are loaded into the AppDomain, it will just work.

Comment: Thanks for that tidbit! Much appreciated.

Comment: tried with this IUnityContainer _container = new UnityContainer();
ViewModelLocationProvider.SetDefaultViewModelFactory((type) =>
    {
        return _container.Resolve(type);
    }); it's not resolving the view model

Comment: i added the above code in app.xaml.cs, its triggering the debug breakpoint in the viewModel constructor, can you share some example

Comment: If you're using the latest version of Prism, you don't have to manually set the SetDefaultViewModelFactory. All you have to do is make sure your convention is returning the correct type to be resolved.  There is a link to a sample in the blog post